# How to route subtasks URL in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with laravel 5.2 and I am developing project management tool. in my application I have projects and each project have tasks and one task may have sub tasks. in each task I have button to create subtasks as following,

```
<a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

when I view my tasks list witch related to each project my url is as following.

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/1
```

now i have subtask form in subtasks folder of view file to enter sub tasks to each task

```
subtasks/subtask.blade.php
```

now I need when I click sub task enter button redirect subtask blade file as url is this way.

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/1/task/1/subtask
```

how can I manage href of sub task add button

```
<a href="" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
```

and My routes?
**Updated**
this is my subtask input form

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask')}}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="task_name" class="form-control" id="name" value="{{ old('task_name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('task_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('task_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Create Task</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

is my subtask form action correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create route like this

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/1/task/1/subtask

Route::get('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask','HomeController@index');
```

For link

```
<a href="{{url('projects/'.$projectId.'/task/'.$taskId.'/subtask')}}" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>`
```

so in controller you can access

```
public function index($projectId,$taskId){

//you can do your query releated task
}
```

Update
if you have not developed controller and you wish to pass via route then

```
Route::get('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask', function ($projectId, $taskId) {

    return view('subtasks/subtask',['projectId'=>$projectId,'taskId'=>$taskId]);
});
```

Comment: can you give me some idea to create controller to inter subtasks

Comment: since you are not using controller .so you can build same way your url as you wish

Comment: also you have a option to pass optional parameter in url .you can check documetns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156206/discussion-between-lilan-and-icoders).